# SQL Server .NET Function Issue

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

A proc I have uses a .NET function to decrypt data from the database.  However, I'm getting this failure from the database.

A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "[Function name]": 
System.ArgumentNullException: Buffer cannot be null.

Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Comment: You added your sample as an answer to your question.

Comment: @yodaj007 OK, where was I supposed to add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, was passing in a null to the function, and that blew it up.  Reversing the way it was called helped to, such as instead of this:

```
select ..
where fn_decrypt(Field) = @myfield
```

I changed it to:

```
declare @myfieldenc ..
set @myfieldenc = fn_encrypt(@myfield)

select ..
where Field = @myfieldenc
```